# Needs to run test in selenium with protected mode settings

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, protected-mode

while using selenium is it possible to run script in selenium if some options(Protected mode settings..) are checked and some are unchecked.
  Or is there any alternate to break Protected mode security to make runs work in IE browser using selenium.??
  In my case protected mode settings are in disabled mode i,e we cannot alter the already done settings??

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your **`Internet Explorer`** Version info. The docs clearly mentions that :

> **`"Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.`**

Additionally, you require to configure the **`InternetExplorerDriver`** with **`ignoreProtectedModeSettings`** set to either **`1`** or **`0`** through **DesiredCapabilities** Class as follows :

```
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",1);
```

> OR

```
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",0);
```